# What is the arrangement of water molecules in a hydration shell around an anion?

Tags: ions

I believe I read somewhere that the hydration shell of ions always has hydrogen on the outside, but I can't relocate the exact whereabouts of this. Thus, I decided to ask here, as to what the arrangement of the water molecules around a anion is (is it both hydrogens pointed inwards to the ion or if one is facing outside, one is facing inside).

Comment: Maybe of interest: J. Phys. Chem. B, 2007, 111 (48), pp 13570–13577
DOI: [10.1021/jp075913v](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp075913v) Also: Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. 2011, 50, 352 – 353 DOI: 10.1002/anie.201004501 http://139.30.122.11/paschek/PAPERS/DPRLAngewandteInt2011.pdf

Comment: Also: Faraday Discuss. Chem. Soc., 1988,85, 137-146; 10.1039/DC9888500137; https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1988/dc/dc9888500137; And this: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ion_hydration.html ; And this thesis: An ab initio study of ion solvation in water by Jasper Martijn Heuft http://www.science.uva.nl/research/its/molsim/Publications/thesis_heuft.pdf (**<- look at Figure 1.5 and 1.6**)